# What Hamiltonian stands for?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I read the derivation of Schrödinger equation.It's like below.

Let's think about the operator U(t+Δt,t) which transform state vecter at time t to time t+Δt.

So ,$|Φ(t+Δt)〉=U(t+Δt,t)|Φ(t)〉$

$〈i|Φ(t+Δt)〉=〈i|∑_jU(t+Δt,t)|j〉〈j|Φ(t)〉$

Then expand  $U(t+Δt,t)$ to $δ_{ij}-\frac{i}{ℏ}H_{ij}Δt$

and get  $iℏ\frac{d〈i|Φ(t)〉}{dt}=∑_jH_{ij}〈j|Φ(t)〉$

Why is the operater U's coefficient of Δt  $-i(Hamiltonian)/ℏ$ ?

Comment: The hamiltonian is the energy of a system, it defines the dynamics of the system. Meanwhile $\hbar$ is the unit of action and has units Joules*Seconds

Comment: How it defines dynamics of the System ?

Comment: The man's name was Schrödinger.

Comment: There are many 'derivations' of the Schrödinger equation, depending on what you take as a starting point. As such, this question is not answerable until you specify *where* you read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $H=i\hbar\partial_t$, $\exp -iH\delta t/\hbar =\exp \delta t \partial_t$, an operator that sends a function $f(t)$ to the Taylor series for $f(t+\delta t)$. Thus we have obtained the time translation operator.

Comment: Thank you for answering.But what I know is why U's coefficient of Δt is -i(Hamiltonian)/ℏ from the point of physics?